# How to do a find in a Resource file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, resources

I am wondering say I have this string "Hi my name is chobo2" and I want to find all the files that have this string. Normally I would do ctrl + f in VS 2010 and do a find.

How do I find this string if it is in a resource file? Right now I have a string in a solution that has many projects. I know the project has at least one resource file but I cannot find the string I am looking for. I might have missed it as the file seems to have many string in it.

Is there any easy way to locate this string value in the resource file? This way I can find the "resource name" and thus find where the string is used in the project.

**Edit**

Just a side note

I opened up the resource file and tried to do a ctrl + f on it(search by current document) but it only searches on the "name" column not the "value" column

Comment: You can search on "Hi my name is chobo2" by `ctrl+shift+F` no problem (resource, code, etc). and if you can't find it in entire solution means you build it dynamically or possibly by string.format like : `string.Format("Hi my name is {0}", name)` so you should search on some part of string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I think this will explain all you need to find the string. ****Cheers**** to vs2010

Comment: Ok that will find me all the resource files. Anyways to do a search through all the resource files value column looking for the string I want?

Comment: Ah I see it looks through the .xml document.

Comment: i think that would be enough for you to find what you intended to find.

Answer (score 3):

Press `Ctrl+Shift+F` and select Entire solution. Then use F8 for navigation on found items. In addition, for finding related resource files, goto `Tools->Option->Project and Solution` and check Track Active Item to true.

Answer (score 3):

In resharper it is very easy -> find usages (or something similar)

But you can use `Ctrl + Shift + F` (select entire solution) in file type section type `*.*` or `*.resx` and click find (on panel below all occurrence should appear) double click should drive you directly to resx file (Xml)

Comment: hmm maybe I am not saying it clear on what I want. I have a string "Hi my name is chobo2". I have no clue what the resource name is(could be Resource.MyName, or Resource.HeyHey, who knows) all I know is the value. "ctrl + f"(with entire solution selected) does not find the value.

Comment: "ctrl  + Shift + F" - did you try it ? (and file types set to *.* or *.resx)  default file type is *.cs i think, so that may be a reason why it not find your string.